# JSON Schema validation in recursive property does not work

Tags: json, validation, recursion, schema

I am developing a JSON Schema and I am having trouble with the validation using recursion. Here a simplified schema and document that shows the problem. I am testing the schema on https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/.

```json
  {
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "items": { "$ref": "#/$defs/questions" }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,

    "$defs": {
        "questions": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
              "anyOf": [
                  {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                          "title": {
                              "type": "object",
                              "patternProperties": {
                                  "^(de|fr|it|en)$": { "type": "string" }
                              }
                          },
                          "description": {
                              "type": "object",
                              "patternProperties": {
                                  "^(de|fr|it|en)$": { "type": "string" }
                              }
                          },
                          "items": { "$ref": "#/$defs/questions" }
                      },
                      "additionalProperties": false
                  },
                  {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                          "id": {
                              "type": "string",
                              "pattern": "^(key1|key2)$"
                          }
                      }
                  }
              ]
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

And here a document that is incorrect according to the schema.

```json
  {
      "items": [
          {
              "id": "key1"
          },
          {
              "title": {
                  "de": "Text Title"
              },
              "description": {
                  "de": "Text Description"
              },
              "items": [
                  {
                      "id": "key3"   // This value is not allowed for property id
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              "hi": "there"     // This whole section does not match any of the anyOf schemas
          }
      ]
  }
```

The validation of the properties works if "key1" in the first element is changed to something not existing like "key3". In the nested "items" array it doesn't

I found this in Stack Overflow: [json-schema-validation-in-recursive-property-does-not-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76321762/json-schema-validation-in-recursive-property-does-not-work)

Unfortunately the tipps there (make properties not required) could not solve my problem.

Some context information. The final documents are questionnaires that are rendered in a browser. We already have a whole bunch of them in production and they work very well. The usage of a schema is now intended for avoiding invalid documents during development by new staff members. In the docuemnt the "items" array contains the questions and the schema of each question depends on its type (single choice, single line, multiple choice, etc.). At the top level "items" should be mandatory, whereas they are optional if nested within an overlying "items" array.

Your help is very much appreciated.
Thank you